# Installing armhf packages on Ubuntu on the Google Compute Engine

Tags: ubuntu, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-17.04

I followed [Debian's Multiarch HOWTO](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) to be able to install `libcholmod3:armhf`. I ran `dpkg --add-architecture armhf` but now if I run `sudo apt-get update` I get an error:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[...]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 192.158.31.252 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 192.158.31.252 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 192.158.31.252 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I see http://europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/ is missing the `binary-armhf` directory. What's the proper way of installing armhf packages on the Google Compute Engine platform?

Answer (score 1):

There are two apparent issues:

## 1. The fetch failures when running `apt-get update`.

This is not actually a problem. As the message says, the errors are just ignored. The errors are gone by adding "[arch=amd64]" on each line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, as described by https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO#Setting_up_apt_sources

## 2. The fact that armhf seemed to be missing at the URLs in those fetch failure messages.

I did a `grep europe-west1 /etc -R` and `/etc/apt/sources.list` showed up. At the top of the file are a few options of making changes:

```
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl
```

To setup Multiarch for armhf on an amd64 Google Platform cloud machine is to add the following source using one of the options above:

```
deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports zesty main universe
```